# Where can I find a good tutorial for py2exe?

Tags: python, wxpython, py2exe

Can somebody point me at a **good** tutorial for py2exe?  I've read over the [official tutorial](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial) but it is rather light on details, compared to all the options one can use when building an executable out of a python script.  For the record, my python script uses Python 2.5.2, wxPython/wxWidgets 2.8 and MySQLdb 1.2.2; so if you have specific tips for py2exe with those packages that would be much appreciated (and yes, I've seen the [Py2EXE and wxPython](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Py2exeAndwxPython) page).

Answer (score 4):

Regarding "Py2EXE and wxPython", the page mentions the import statement "from wxPython.wx import *".  This is the old wxPython (several years old, I think).  In my app, I just do "import wx", and I don't have any major troubles.

I have one tip for wxPython and py2exe: you need a manifest if you want your app to look any good on Windows XP.  This email has details: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2004-June/268126.html

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to release py2exe GUI so that you can easy compile your apps without writing setup scripts. More info [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/py2exegui/)

Comment: Fix the hyperlink to the sourceforge project

Comment: Sounds like a good project, I'll keep an eye out for a usable release.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about a better tutorial, but there is some information to be found at the news list.

http://news.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.py2exe

Answer (score 1):

Since this question was asked, I've updated the official py2exe tutorial to include substantially more information about bundling the Microsoft C runtime DLL.
http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial#Step5

If anyone reading this question knows about things which they think are missing from the official tutorial, can I encourage them to add that knowledge to the official tutorial, which is a wiki.